# "FILE...is not a Debian format archive"

Tags: debian, rtl-sdr

EDIT: I downloaded a Debian package from debian.org website (via `wget "ftp.us.debian.org/debian"`) however the package downloads as a text file and not *.deb on my Debian Buster. Why is that?

I was ultimately able to install the package on my Debian (with some unment dependencies) by downloading the package first to my Mac (which did download the file as *.deb) and then opening that file on my Debian computer.

Comment: Welcome but I'm a bit baffled.  What exactly are you trying to do as Macs do not run Debian and the Pi has an Arm processor so could not run native x86 code that could run on the Mac?

Comment: How does the package download on the RasPi?

Comment: so it downloads as a .deb on the Mac, but you can't install it on the Mac - so, what does the pi have to do with this question? also, can you show exactly which file you downloaded

Comment: Thanks. Seed edits above for clarification